# Get array of sequences for array of interval arrays in OPL

Tags: cplex, opl

So I want to define multiple sequences (an array of them).
I have this:

```
dvar interval casy[d in 1..Domy][ukol in Ukoly] size Trvani[ukol];

dvar sequence S[d in 1..Domy] in i in casy[d];
```

I get an error: `Cannot use domain type dvar interval[][Ukoly] for dvar sequence`.
But when I use:

```
dvar interval casy[ukol in Ukoly] size Trvani[ukol];

dvar sequence S in i in casy;
```

everything just runs fine.
Also, when I use

```
dvar interval casy[d in 1..Domy][ukol in Ukoly] size Trvani[ukol];

dvar sequence S[d in 1..Domy] in i in casy;
```

it works, but the sequences are for all the intervals, which I dont want. I want to have different sequences separately for each array of intervals, indexed by `d`.

I just can't understand why would it use the array of intervals when I declare it normally, but would complain when I pull the same exact interval from an array by its index.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the sched_sequence example in OPL CPLEX you have an example of array of sequences:

```
dvar sequence workers[w in WorkerNames] in
    all(h in Houses, t in TaskNames: Worker[t]==w) itvs[h][t]
```

that should help you

regards